# PhpStorm export settings to .jar on Windows

Tags: windows, phpstorm, settings

It is possible to export all settings (keymap, plugins etc) to .jar archive on Windows? In `File` menu I don't have this option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just disable settings sync plugins (IDE Settings Sync and Settings Repository).

`File | Export/Import Settings...` are intentionally disabled when these plugins are used to avoid confusion, as they export/import local settings rather than shared ones.

See comments in [IDEA-198980](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198980).